# Validating File Date on Data Import Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

We use an automation activity to import a file from an FTP location to a Marketing Cloud data extension. The activity uses wildcards to pull in a file with the most recent date.

Question: is there a way to ensure the automation activity (or combination of activities) imports a file posted within the past several days.

We are working with a third-party who sometimes forgets to post a file every Monday. We want to see if the automation can somehow verify if the file is either old (i.e. it's last week's file, not this week's file) or can let us know if a recent file is not posted.

Comment: Did you consider using a File Drop automation instead? File drop automations begin automatically when a file is dropped into a designated Enhanced FTP folder rather than on a schedule. Help: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_triggered_automations.htm&type=5

Comment: Complicating matters is the file needs to be decrypted using Marketing Cloud's standard keys.

Comment: You can decrypt in file drop automation like you would in any else